# Not able to start the zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am downloaded the zookeeper from link https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.6.1/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz

My Java home path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151.

When I try to start the zkServer.cmd I am getting message as "\Java\jdk1.8.0_151 was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Java 8 is end-of-life, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Put you java path into double quote, like this (in enviroment variables) :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151"
```

or change your java installation path to another folder such as :

```
C:\java
```